# Rename SQL Result file to Date format "MMDDYYYY" Automatically?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, csv

I have the below SQL query which works for me very fine. however, I want to make my .csv file name as a date format "MMDDYYYY", which means whenever the job is executed on a daily basis it should automatically make the name of "Results.csv" to a current system date when the job was executed, how I can edit my code below to cater the same.

```
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_send_dbmail @profile_name='default',
@recipients='dev@null.com',
@subject='test mail',
@query= 'SELECT * from testtable',
@attach_query_result_as_file=1,
@query_attachment_filename = 'Results.csv',
@query_result_separator = ','
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this:

```
DECLARE @FileName varchar(20)
SELECT @FileName = 'Results' +  REPLACE(CONVERT(varchar(10),GETDATE(),101),'/','') + '.csv'
EXEC sp_send_dbmail @profile_name='default',
@recipients='dev@null.com',
@subject='test mail',
@query= 'SELECT * from testtable',
@attach_query_result_as_file=1,
@query_attachment_filename = @FileName ,
@query_result_separator = ','
```

Comment: I tried the above, but it shows me incorrect syntax near +??

Comment: @Oman - There was an extra comma after the filename which I have removed. Try again

Comment: I tried also but it's still showing me Incorrect syntax near '+' and there's a red line under the '+' after 'Results'

Comment: Modified to compute the complete filename before assigning to query_attachment_filename.

Comment: Increased @filename to varchar(20)

Comment: Thank you so much for the help :)

Comment: To know more about how to change the dates in desired format you can check the BOL https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx